# Android - gain priviledges to write to secondary sd card at runtime

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-permissions

```
The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission must only grant write access to the primary external 
storage on a device. Apps must not be allowed to write to secondary external storage 
devices, except in their package-specific directories as allowed by synthesized 
permissions. Restricting writes in this way ensures the system can clean up files
when applications are uninstalled.
```

However i've seen that it is possible to gain write priviledges at runtime  (Proof of concept: Total Commander) using the System File Explorer to select a folder for which write is allowed after the folder selection is complete. However I can't seem to find an example of how to implement this. Any help with that? A screenshot of the folder selection that I'm reffering to is shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guss i ll answer my own question for future visitors...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    boolean finish = true;
    boolean selectionWasCorrect = false;
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){ 
         //Take persistant permission. This way you can modify the selected folder ever after a device restart.
         Uri treeUri = data.getData();
         int takeFlags = data.getFlags()  & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
         getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, takeFlags); 
    }
}
```

All these are applicable only from KIT_KAT and above

Comment: Please note, this is only available from LOLLIPOP and not KIT_KAT.

Comment: FYI. This gives you permanent access permission to the selected directory. To read/write files on SD, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862675/android-sd-card-write-permission-using-saf-storage-access-framework