# I get open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) error when I try write data to SD card in Android 5.1, why?

Tags: android

I need to save some data to SD card , I have add the permission  
 to AndroidManifest.xml file, and I can get the correct result when I test it in Android 4.12 mobile.

But I get open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) error when  I test it in Android 5.1 mobile, why?

BTW, I have read the artical [Android 6.0 open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied) and [Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android) , but now my mobile is SamSung  Android 5.1

**Code**

```
 private void ActionUploadFiles(Map<String, String> files,IHTTPSession session,String uploadFolder){

        try{
            Set<String> keys = files.keySet();

            for (String key:keys) {
                String location = files.get(key);
                File source = new File(location);

                String filename= session.getParms().get(key);
                filename=FilenameUtils.getName(filename);

                File target = new File(uploadFolder,filename);

                FileUtils.copyFile(source,target);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Utility.LogError("Upload Error: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.dodata.wifi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {      
        multiDexEnabled true

        applicationId "info.dodata.wifi"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.04"
        archivesBaseName = "WiFiFileTransfer-V" + versionName
    }

    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "info.dodata.wifi"
        }

        pro {
            applicationId "info.dodata.wifi.pro"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IsDebugMode", "false"
        }

        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IsDebugMode", "true"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: which `SD card`? Are you talking about emulated SD card (external storage), or physical SD card (like microSD, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! It's physical SD card, I test the code in both real Android 4.2 mobile and real android 5.1 mobile.

Comment: it's quite hard to write to physical SD card in Android 4.4+. You can't do it using regular way. You will have to use Storage Access Framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862675/android-sd-card-write-permission-using-saf-storage-access-framework

Comment: It is completely unclear how you determined the path to the SD card. Moreover you did not tell what the path is exactly. Please supply all info.

Comment: To greenapps: I hope I can write all path of SD card.

Comment: What folder are you trying to access?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the run-time permissions introduced from Android Lollipop. What you can do is enable permission. To do this, go to

`Settings -> Apps -> YOUR_APP -> Permissions`

and enable permissions and then test it.

For adding run-time permission, you can ask inside `onCreate()`.

```
String[] permission ={Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(EditDisplayPicture.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(EditDisplayPicture.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(YourActivity.this, permission, 1);
    }
} else proceedFurther();
```

And then listen for permission acceptance or denial like this,

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        proceedFurther();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "You need to give permission in order to proceed further.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but I think it should be if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(EditDisplayPicture.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
 ||  ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(EditDisplayPicture.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)  ... right?

Comment: If you want to proceed when both permissions are enabled, then you should `AND` the permissions. In anyways, `&&` is recommended because you always ask permission you need in your app and it's pointless to proceed if anyone is enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied

Comment: Ronny Kibet use OR instead of AND

Comment: It's basic programming concept, you can use it how you want it to be. You know what does `&&` and `||` mean, so use it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

because you have `targetSdkVersion 23` thats why you get Security exception, you have to downgrade to `targetSdkVersion 22` or add run time permission. please check this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

> Update : [open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527767/open-failed-eacces-permission-denied)

Comment: Thanks! I have set targetSdkVersion 22, but I still get open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) !

Comment: You will failed to notice one thing **If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower** and **If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher**
This answer wont help

Answer (score 0):

Starting Kitkat, Android restricted write access to SDCARD to third party applications. They introduced the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) for performing the operations. To write to files on the SDCard you will need to use these API's.

For Some devices running Lollipop, you can gain write access to files using these api's. As I haven't used the api myself, I cannot provide you with a snippet. But the link will surely help you solve the problem.

You can take a look at [Es Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) to see the flow of how they handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because your device is not allowing the application to access the storage.

Generally this error comes with the permission denied, so just go to the settings in your device if you are using the physical device as emulator to run the app and then go to application manager. Find your app and go to permissions and then allow the permission storage for your app and try again.