# Xamarin.Forms Android cannot access USB OTG folder

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, storage, unauthorized, usb-otg

I'm on an Android 5.0 device where a usb mass storage is mounted at "/storage/usbotg" via USB OTG cable. 
Unfortunately from my app I only have read access to that folder. Please note that I set the write external storage permission as I'm able to write to device storage.

I post the following code as reference:

```
string Root = "/storage/usbotg";                        
string[] Dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Root);

string NewFolder = Path.Combine(Root, "NewFolder");          
Directory.CreateDirectory(NewFolder);
```

This gives me an exception on the last line (but I'm able to list subdirectories in Dirs)

Exception:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Exception Message:
Access to the path "/storage/usbotg/NewFolder" is denied.

If I use:

```
string Root =  "/storage/emulated/0";
```

everything is working fine and the "NewFolder" is created.

What I'm missing? How can I write to that folder?

I'm using Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which file browser app did you use?

Comment: Please use `try-catch` to get the `Message`.

Comment: ES File Explorer is the the file browser I'm using, I think also others will work too.

Exception is

System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Exception message is

Access to the path "/storage/usbotg/NewFolder" is denied.

Comment: Micro SD cards and usb drives are readonly for Android > 4. Only one app specific directory is writable. Have a look at getExternalFilesDirs(). It seems ES File Explorer knows some tricks so it can write. If you want to write to the whole sd card / storage then use the storage access framework. And try other file explorer apps. And you did not mention if you can write on a micro sd card.

Comment: Thanks for your help greenapps, when using getExternalFilesDir with USB OTG plugged it only returns one path on device storage: 
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files, also getExternalFilesDirs documentation states "The returned paths do not include transient devices, such as USB flash drives connected to handheld devices."

Comment: Tried with another File Manager, Total Commander, cannot write to usb otg from there. Tried again with ES File Explorer cannot write from there too! Sorry I was wrong when said I can. So, seems that on this device I only have read access to usb otg. Is that normal? What is the correct way of getting usb otg path from android?

Comment: With SD card inserted I got an additional entry returned by getExternalFilesDirs() pointing to a specific folder where I have write permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing data outside your application's private storage using the file system is more restricted with each Android version.

The recommended options are :

- Use `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs`, ...  : this gives you one or more directories specific to you application (usually directories named after the package name). This does not work for removable media, unless they're adopted.
- Use the Storage Access Framework : ask the user (using [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)) to choose the storage root. You can then manage the content of the picked directory through the SAF API. You can [persist the permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)), so you only need to ask the user once. It seems that it is [what ES File explore does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36862675/1283554) to get write permission.

A (much) more [detailed explanation](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) by Mark Murphy.

Comment: Thanks bwt, this clarified things a lot!