# How to do file operations (create/write/update/delete files) using the Flutter "saf" Package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, storage-access-framework, saf

How to do file operations (create/write/update/delete files) using the Flutter **"saf"** Package.

link:- **pub.dev/packages/saf**

I didn't find any solutions on Google. I want to use Android "Storage Access Framework" and let users select a folder on External Storage. In this folder, I want to save my app files that users can access.

Previously I was using app-specific storage (Android/data/com.myapp). But from Android 11 users can't access this folder due to Security Update from Google.

Any solutions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
bool? isGranted = await saf.getDirectoryPermission(isDynamic: false);

if (isGranted != null && isGranted) {
  // Perform some file operations
  // **But How?**
} else {
  // failed to get the permission
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the folder access by using Storage Access Framework then you can not perform file handling operations on this folder by using the dart: 'dart: io' package.
Check URL:  [SAF root gives your application access to the corresponding storage, but only through the SAF API, not directly via the filesystem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862675/android-sd-card-write-permission-using-saf-storage-access-framework) Also, from Android 11 and above, without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, accessing data from external storage using java.io.File is almost completely deprecated.

I found two Packages that support **Storage Access Framework** in the flutter.

[shared_storage: ^0.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/saf/versions/1.0.3+3)

[saf: ^1.0.3+3](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_storage/versions/0.2.0)

**shared_storage 0.2.0** provide us

```
Uri uri = await openDocumentTree(); 
List<UriPermission> persistedUris = await persistedUriPermissions();
```

and

```
/// Create a new file using the `SAF` API
final newDocumentFile = await createDocumentFile(
  mimeType: 'text/plain',
  content: 'My Plain Text Comment Created by shared_storage plugin',
  displayName: 'CreatedBySharedStorageFlutterPlugin',
  directory: anySelectedUriByTheOpenDocumentTreeAPI,
);

print(newDocumentFile);
```

By above method can create file by using *writeAsString()* instead of *writeAsBytes()*. But for creating an **Image** file we required **writeAsBytes()**.

**saf 1.0.3+3** having a method createFileAsBytes() in document_file.dart but not available for usage in current version.

But in the future, both packages will provide these APIs.

***Solution:***
**For now, I have solved this issue by using both packages simultaneously.**

Add packages in your pubspec.yaml:

[shared_storage: ^0.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/saf/versions/1.0.3+3)

[saf: ^1.0.3+3](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_storage/versions/0.2.0)

And use the following code

```
void createFileBySAF(String fileName, Uint8List uint8list) {

  /*From: shared_storage: ^0.2.0*/
  Uri uri = await openDocumentTree(); 
  
  /*From: saf: ^1.0.3+3*/
  Map<String, dynamic> result = await MethodChannel('com.ivehement.plugins/saf/documentfile').invokeMapMethod<String, dynamic>('createFile', <String, dynamic>{
    'mimeType': 'any',
    'content': uint8list,
    'displayName': fileName,
    'directoryUri': '$uri',
  });
  print(result);
}
```

For the Update and Delete operations find the usage in https://github.com/ivehement/saf/blob/master/lib/src/storage_access_framework/document_file.dart

Comment: Can you please show me how to read those files that I have created with SAF?

Comment: Sorry, I have not yet worked on that, but may be you will get in updated version of shared_storage: ^0.3.1 (URL: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_storage/versions/0.3.1). But definitely if it get me then I will show you.

Answer (score 1):

**First get permission for the directory on which operation to be performed using saf flutter package**

```
import 'package:saf/saf.dart';

await Saf.getDynamicDirectoryPermission()
```

***Files operation in Flutter using dart: io core package***

*Create*

```
var myFile = File('file.txt');
```

*Read*

```
File('file.txt').readAsString().then((String contents) {
    print(contents);
  });
```

*Write*

```
final filename = 'file.txt';
var file = await File(filename).writeAsString('some content');
```

*Delete*

```
var myFile = File('file.txt');
myFile.delete();
```

*Source:* https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-io/File-class.html

Comment: How can I put this file (var myFile = File('file.txt')) inside that folder that I got permission with saf. My code: `Future<void> _saveInFolderWithPermission() async {
  await Saf.getDynamicDirectoryPermission();
  var myFile = File('file.text');
}` But this does nothing. I know how to create a file and perform operations on it. What I want to do is, I want to put some files in a folder that the user selected using SAF and then perform operations on those files. I mean I want to use that folder to save my app's user data and perform operations on it, that's all. Is it possible using SAF?

Comment: Just a simple thing, I got permission of a folder. How can I write/save file into this folder. How can I read file from this folder? How can I delete file from this folder?. I got permission of a folder that's awesome. Then I need to use this folder nah? How to use this folder to save files and delete and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this [Link](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)
SAF is only use for permission handling. Write, read operation is performed by dart.

**Find the correct local path**

> ```
> Future<String> get _localPath async {
>  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
>  return directory.path;
>   }
> ```

**Create a reference to the file location**

> Future get _localFile async {
> final path = await _localPath;
> return File('$path/counter.txt');
> }

** Write data to the file **

> Future writeCounter(int counter) async {
> final file = await _localFile;

> // Write the file
> return file.writeAsString('$counter');
> }

Comment: I got it but, How can I write file in that folder, that I got permission using SAF. I tried but failed can you show me how?

Comment: I don't know how. In there official documentation, there is no clue to create file with SAF.